# How Can I Get MinTTY (Cygwin Terminal) to Open gvim in a New Window?

Tags: vim, cygwin

I have installed mintty. After that I am not able to open gvim. As suggested in same question for emacs I use:
1) mintty gvim

this opens a new window with message :

E233: cannot open displayE852: The child process failed to start the GUI
Press ENTER or type command to continue

Also I have set : export DISPLAY=":0"

what I am doing wrong

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You probably don't have an X server running.  Look [here](http://x.cygwin.com/) for instructions on setting it up.  Personally, I find it easier to just uninstall the cygwin version of gvim and use the windows version instead.

Comment: Thanks a lot Karl. Please let me know how to use windows version of gvim from Cygwin. Also I closed X terminal from quit option now I get error message like:startxwin: Another X server instance is running on DISPLAY :0
: Resource temporarily unavailable

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem when starting gvim and was getting the error message as above.

My default DISPLAY setting is :0.0

However, I noticed in the output of my startxwin, that it said

"""
    Rules = "base" Model = "pc105" Layout = "us" Variant = "none" Options = "none"
    winMultiWindowXMsgProc - DISPLAY=:2.0
    winInitMultiWindowWM - DISPLAY=:2.0
    winProcEstablishConnection - winInitClipboard returned.
"""

I set my display to :2.0 and it works now.
ie
export DISPLAY=:2.0

Hope this helps.

[Further to this, the script seems to check /tmp/.X11-unix/Xn where n in Xn is a number.
It seems I had X0 and X1 already there, probably leftover from an older bad shutdown.
Deleting this seems to restore it back to using :0.0
]

Comment: Thanks!  I had that problem, too!  Note that ls may display the file as /tmp/.X11-unix/X0=, but that '=' is a rare filetype indicator.  gvim still doesn't work for me, though.  Same error.

Answer (score 1):

you can define a function in your .bash_profile (you need to make sure gvim.exe is in your $PATH)

```
vim() {
  echo "cygstart gvim.exe --remote-tab-silent $(cygpath -w "$@")"
  cygstart gvim.exe --remote-tab-silent $(cygpath -w "$@")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For me, gvim was being picked up from /usr/bin/gvim
I installed gvim as a windows application and then invoked it from its windows path directly as

```
[cygwin$] /cygdrive/C/Program\ Files\ \(x86\)/Vim/vim74/gvim
```

And it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Like user2250246, I just punted on trying to get cygwin's gvim to start working again, but I didn't want to type or alias gvim.  (Which I probably should've. The alias is easier.)

I added the Windows app's gvim's path to my Windows environment variables:

1. Get the path to gvim by finding its icon in your Start menu and
   right-clicking on it, then opening Properties.  Find the Target link
   and copy all but the final 'gvim.exe'.
2. Go to Control Panel -> System -> Advanced System Settings -> Environment
   Variables -> System variables. Select Path.  Click Edit.
   Paste in that path at the start.  Click OK. Click OK.

Then Cygwin will put your Windows gvim on its path, but it will put /usr/bin ahead of it on its own path.  So

3. mv /usr/bin/gvim /usr/bin/gvim-screwed-up

   mv /usr/bin/gvimdiff /usr/bin/gvimdiff-screwed-up

and your cygwin will find & run the Windows-installed gvim, with or without your cygwin X server running.

Unfortunately, it will no longer load your cygwin .vimrc!  You'll have to fix that yourself.